# syntax to return json to calling function from jquery .ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, return

maybe it can't be done or maybe I just can't find it, either way I'm new to jquery and it's driving me nuts. I want to accept the return from an ajax call in the calling function, preferably a JSON object. I am explicitly looking for a way to handle the response outside of success/complete callback functions. Can someone please give me the proper syntax for this? The pseudo code is something like

```
SomeFunction()
{
    var JSON_Containter = .ajax({stuff...});

    DO other stuff with JSON response...
}
```

Thanks very much for your assistance!

Comment: You know AJAX is async right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return value from ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632039/return-value-from-ajax-call)

Comment: [This](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) might work for you.

Comment: yes, I know AJAX is async. Asynchronous JavaScript And XML... I'm trying to work with Jeditable, submit to function instead of url. I looked at the code, Jeditable seems to run with async to false by default. Jeditable passes my function the submit value and expects a return of the same. I want to be able to alter the value and return it post-server side validation, but have been having a bugger of a time of it. Even when my ajax call is set to sync mode, the Jeditable text area just freezes up. I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm new to client side scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to not use callback functions would be to make the AJAX request *synchronous* so that the code waits for it to complete:

```
var responseObj;

$.ajax({ 
    ..., 
    async: false, 
    success: function(data) { responseObj = data; }});

// Do stuff with responseObj
```

I wouldn't recommend doing things this way.  You don't want the UI freezing while waiting for the AJAX response.  Here's a better approach:

```
function SomeFunction(successCallback, errorCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        ..., 
        success: successCallback,
        error: errorCallback
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. works fine. I went with the former (see above comment). Thanks

Comment: i tried using JSON as well, and its really driving me nuts. its so dissapointing. i see a lot of sample codes but i just dont get it! its so frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), but you are still going to need to use a success callback, because of the way AJAX works - the A stands for "asynchronous", after all.

But don't forget that inside that success callback, you have access to the variables from the parent scope as well, so you should be able to do what you need within that callback.